# Deleting specific sheets and those which do not meet a criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro where I create a number of sheets that take their names from the values in column c, cell 7 onwards in a sheet called "Schedule". I am using the following code for that

```
Sub CreateDataSheets()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20161215
Dim xRg As Variant
Dim wSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wBk As Excel.Workbook
Set wSh = ActiveSheet
Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each xRg In wSh.Range("C7", Range("C7").End(xlDown))
    If Not IsError(xRg) Then
        If xRg <> "" Then
            If Not WorksheetExists((xRg)) Then
                With wBk
                   .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count), Type:="L:\London\General\Reference & Tools\Software\BIM\IiA_Specifications\Excel\Uk Specification Template.xltx"
                    ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next xRg
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now I need another Macro where if I change or delete any of these values in Column C, I want to create new updated ones and delete all the sheets that are redundant. While doing this, I want to retain the sheets called Schedule, Home and CoverSheet. Below is the code I tried to write but that would not work.

```
Sub DeleteNewSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne() As Variant
Dim wsName As Variant
Dim Matched As Boolean
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = Range("C7:C11")

ArrayOne = Array("Home", "Schedule", "CoverSheet", DirArray.Value)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In Sheets
    Matched = False
    For Each wsName In ArrayOne
        If wsName = ws.Name Then
            Matched = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not Matched Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Would really appreciate any ideas...

Comment: "Would not work" or does not work? And if the latter, please provide details of error messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

`DirArray` is beeing created as a `Variant` and the position `4` of your Array `ArrayOne` is actually another array and not a string.

To fix it, initialize the `ArrayOne` just like this:

```
ArrayOne = Array("Home", "Schedule", "CoverSheet")

Dim Name As Variant
For Each Name In DirArray
    If Name <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve ArrayOne(UBound(ArrayOne) + 1)
        ArrayOne(UBound(ArrayOne)) = Name
    End If
Next
```

It will also not consider empty values on the range you selected.

Consider changing your removing steps as on [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832913/6591514)

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a changing set is often a bad idea. Do something like this instead

```
For i = Sheets.Count to 1 Step -1
    If ....
        Sheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```